# How to use flush() if (session) user is logged in? - Realtime notification

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, flush

How to use flush() if (session) user is logged in?

I tried to use the following code to check notifications when user is logged in but there is a problem: 
Flush doesn't work if I use session
Can't fetch query without session because `to` = '$iam' and $iam is user id

```
<?php 
session_start();//Start session
ob_start();
include("../system/connect.php");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");//It means don't use session, so it's almost oposite of session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
$iam=$userRow['user_id'];
$id=int($_GET['id']);
if($id>=1){
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE `to` = '$iam' `seen` = '1' order by `id`");
$c=mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "data: " . $c . "\n\n";// Send it in a message
flush();
}
}
?>
```

Also there is another way which is more simple and too probable:
I can use $_GET['i'] as user id but by the way user will be able to count another users notifications, it's just a bug

> ```
> include("../system/connect.php");
> header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
> header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
> $iam=int($_GET['i']);
> $id=int($_GET['id']);
>
> if($id>=1){
> $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE `seen` = '1' order by `id`");
> $c=mysqli_num_rows($result);
>
>
> echo "data: " . $c . "\n\n";   // Send it in a message
> flush();
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

In conclusion, I need the first way in correct form, help me please

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
<?php 
include("../system/connect.php");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
session_start();
ob_start();
ob_flush();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ 
$iam=$_SESSION['user'];//Query replaced with SESSION
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE `to` = '$iam' and `seen` = '1' order by `id`");
$c=mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "data: " . $c . "\n\n";// Send it in a message

flush();
}

?>
```